# Draw arrows on lines in specific point

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom, svg

I would place arrows with a specific position + directions

I'm using markers to do that

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit,OnInit  {
  trains = [{
    progression:30,
    direction: {
      from :'Station3',
      to: 'Station2'
    }},
    {
    progression:90,
    direction: {
      from :'Station2',
      to: 'Station3'
    }
  }]

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.trains.map(elm=> {
    let path= document.getElementById('path9');
    let pt = path.getPointAtLength(elm.progression);
    let marker= document.getElementById("mid");
    marker.setAttribute('refX','0');
    path.setAttribute('marker-end', 'url(#mid)');
    let svg =document.getElementById('Calque_1');
    console.log(svg)
    })
  }
}
```

Actually no marker is shown , i don't understand why ? I'm setting `marker-end` to the path so it should be printed on screen.

Here's a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-resizing-acq2mb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: What is `svg-path-properties` and why do you think it provides getTangentAtLength?

Comment: I think using tangent to be able to calculate the  cosinus of the  angle of the arrow's orientation, it's a supposition

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `<marker>` element and `orient` attribute. This attribute defines the orientation of the marker relative to the shape it is attached to.

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker)

Comment: You can only put markers on vertices, not at arbitrary points on a curve.

Comment: as @RobertLongson mentioned it, If I'm not mistaken, you can only draw arrows on start, end, middle and when line changes direction , in my case I should draw arrows on specific positions.